# SoapUI testing with Android and byte arrays

Tags: android, testing, soap, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to do some SOAP testing and I can't find out how to pass a byte[].

I use SoapUI for the tests. I pasted the WSDL and I was able to see the available requests in the list.

```
The WSDL link is: http://54.243.147.122:8080/ASEServer/services/Android?wsdl
```

The android application that has been developed does various tasks that need connection to the Soap server. One of them is the log in procedure. An object is being created and then it gets transformed into a byte array (byte[]) that is being sent to the server.

I cannot really understand how to pass a byte array in the 'envelope' in order to get a response.

I need help desperately, so any suggestion are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send a byte array SOAP U you must first decode your byte array as BASE64. Than simply paste your base64 encoded string to the soap envelope. There are some online converter to convert hexadecimal strings to base64 string. But if you want to do it your self here is an example.

```
public class App {

private static final String TR_MESSAGE = "Hello!, öÖ çÇ ğĞ üÜ ıİ şŞ";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] trUTF16 = TR_MESSAGE.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
    String result = new BigInteger(1, trUTF16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);

    String rebuild = new String(trUTF16, Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
    System.out.println("Rebuild: " + rebuild);

    System.out.println("BASE64: " + new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(trUTF16)));
}}
```